# Trying to pull a random ".tif" image from folder and print image

Tags: python, image, jupyter-notebook, tiff

I have created a definition that loads every image from a called folder. I am now trying to create a code that will either 1) load a specific image when indexed, and/or 2) load an image at random. I have attached two screenshots of my code and the error I am receiving.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQKrV.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/toXkI.png

Comment: Please cut & paste your code as text into your question not as screen shots. This allows people to try your code without having to type it all out, which honestly most people wont bother to do & hence you limit the help you will get.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to concatenate the directory path with the file name:

```
with open(os.path.join(rat110_GF_path, random_filename)) as file
    lines = file.readlines()
```